# Removing an active action adapter would result in a KeyError on form submit. Plone 4 PloneFormGen error

Tags: plone, plone-4.x, ploneformgen

This error is back in PloneFormGen 1.7.12 using Plone 4.3.3 It was in the alpha version earlier and it was fixed.  I resubmitted it as a bug report.

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPageTemplate, line 91, in call
Module Products.CMFFormController.BaseControllerPageTemplate, line 27, in _call
KeyError: 'form.submitted'
```

This was caused by removing the mailer adapter. I tried adding it back, but the problem is still there. Is there a fix to make the form work again?

This is the link to the bug report.  https://github.com/smcmahon/Products.PloneFormGen/issues/154

To duplicate the problem, edit the form and uncheck the mailer under action adapter.  Save and submit the form.  The error appears immediately.  Add the mailer back in and save.  Submit the form.  The problem is still there.

I tried creating a new Plone site with only PloneFormGen added on the same server and a different server.  Same versions of software.  The problem did not duplicate in either case.

Comment: Not reproducable to me with the given versions. Could you please provide a more concrete "steps-to-reproduce"-description and a link to the bug-report you're refering to? TIA.

Comment: I edited the entry and added the information you requested.  If anything else would help, let me know.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks for the description. The steps work for me. Is this also happening in a freshly created Plonsite with no addons installed besides PFG? Please give further feedback in the bug-report, you linked to.

Comment: I added your request to the text above.  I will add it to the bug report.

Comment: Thanks Joe Bigler, I clicked to close this quest now, 'cause its more of a bug-report.

Comment: I closed the bug report.  It's not reproducible in a new Plone site so it is unlikely it will be resolved.  I would like to know what the original cause and fix was in the alpha version.  I couldn't find any details in the bug report.